# How to know when an synchronously-invoked Lambda function has timed out

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I invoke another Lambda function (B) from my main Lambda function (A). B has its timeout set to two minutes. I actually invoke B several times, and I want as many of them to complete as possible within two minutes. If any of them don't complete within two minutes (they're highly variable and unpredictable), I just live without the result from those ones.

How can I detect when B has timed out, so I can carry on with the rest of my code? I was expecting Lambda to return a response with some kind of status when it times out, but it seems that since the function times out, it just craps out altogether and there's nothing to return a status.

All I actually get is an exception thrown saying that the signature has expired after five minutes. This is useless though because it means three minutes have elapsed between the function timing out and this exception being thrown (whilst not only risking A timing out as well, but also whilst I'm paying AWS for running A for nothing).

I can post the code but it's just the standard C# code for invoking a Lambda function.

Edit: Note that B runs blocking code in a third party library, so I can't have anything that anticipates the timeout and returns out of the function with a response.

Comment: What's the type of exception being thrown? Usually there are specific timeout exceptions so you know when there is a timeout.

Comment: Have you tried setting timeout on the client side? You can configure your lambda SDK client to timeout after 2 minutes.

Comment: @beautifulcoder The exception says `Signature expired: 20230625T211912Z is now earlier than 20230625T212020Z (20230625T212520Z - 5 min.)`. This is thrown five minutes after invoking B. B is set in AWS Console to time out after two minutes, so no exception is being thrown because it times out.

Comment: @TofigHasanov I'm not quite sure what you mean. I couldn't find any way of setting B's timeout from A (which would be incredibly useful because ideally I'd calculate it and not have to have it fixed at two minutes). And even if I could that wouldn't help with the problem I posted here, because I still don't know when B times out.

Comment: You can’t set B’s timeout from A, but you can set timeout on the client, so that client does not wait longer than 2 minutes for response from B. You can do that by providing custom HttpClient when initializing the AWS SDK client for Lambda

Comment: Thanks, @TofigHasanov. I haven't explained how the whole architecture works because it isn't really relevant. However, I should say that the client isn't involved here. A can run for up to 15 minutes and generates a dataset. Some desirable elements of this data are generated by B, which returns a result to A. Once B is done, I need to ensure that A has enough time to finish its work. A is the function that returns a response to the client. The client knows nothing about B. So it's A, not the client, that needs to know when B times out.

Comment: Okay, what I've done is to use `Task.WhenAny()` to run InvokeAsync() and another task in parallel. The other task just runs for two minutes unless it receives a cancellation token. If InvokeAsync() finishes first then I cancel the other task and I have my result. If the 'timer' task finishes first then I'll know the InvokeAsync has timed out because two minutes are over. I'll need to nuance the timings a little to avoid any thread racing, and I still have no way of setting the timout on B dynamically (I may even create several identical Bs with different timouts...).

Comment: @RobotHead I think you misunderstood what I meant. I am not talking about setting timeout of function A. Does your function A invoke function B? The code which invokes function B is likely using AWS SDK Lambda library, where you instantiate lambda client first and then call "invoke" API and pass function B name/arn + input params. In that place where you call function B from A, you can set up a custom clientside timeout. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thanks, @TofigHasanov. I already tried that. Unfortunately, it leaves me in the same situation, which is that in order to have different timeouts, I have to have multiple versions of B. If I just have one version of B to cater for all timeout values, then if I need a shorter timeout I'm always going to have multiple B's running after that time, costing me money.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a relatively simple workaround.

1. Lambda function A sends Lambda function B the timeout time along with the rest of the request payload.
2. Lambda function B then sets up two tasks - one (B1) to do the work and another (B2) that waits for the timeout time.
3. B1 and B2 are then invoked via Task.WhenAny().
4. If B1 completes first then I return the calculation result.
5. If B2 completes first then I return a result saying that it timed out.
6. In either case, B completes cleanly and the instance becomes available for another invocation (or closes if it isn't used again of course).

This means that I can calcuate the timeout in A, and if that's enough time for B to give me a result then great. If it doesn't then that's okay too, and B never runs for longer than I need it to, and therefore doesn't waste resources.

Comment: Nice, without a timeout exception this is probably your best option.